# If inside of double loop

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

Inside of double loop I create subset of data for each combination of Tv stations with months which is done by loops. For example I have monthsnumbers 7,8,9 and stations A,B,C. It happens that for Month 9 there is no station C.
Then subset is empty and function throws and error of no possible aggregation.

So as you can see I tried to use if statement that if there are 0 rows don't continue with the code but go on to the next loop.

But I still get the same error fck. message

can you please navigate me ?

```
for (Mesic in monthnumbers){



      for (Stanica in TVstations){

          Client<-data[data$month ==Mesic & data$Channel_group1 ==Stanica & data$Brand == brand, ]
          if (nrow(Client)!=0)
    ###some code
   Client_AGG<-aggregate(formula= Client$BUYING_GRPs ~ Client$Brand,data= Client,FUN = sum)
    ###some code
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Follow your `if` statement with brackets for the conditional code: `if (nrow(Client != 0)) { #some code}`. Or you use `if (nrow(Client) == 0) next`.

Comment: Or, as is likely the case, you don't use for loops at all. The `dplyr` or `data.table` packages can probably do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Like Gregor commented, there is likely a better way of going about this.

But a quick patch might be to put the error check before the Client<- line because that's where it's looking for a channel that doesn't exist. Check if data$Channel_group1 == Stanica even exists before trying to get data from it.

Another option using for loops is to cycle through what you know is there with something like this:

```
subsetindex <- unique(data[ ,c('month','Channel_group1')])
for(i in 1:nrow(subsetindex)){
  Client<-data[data$month ==subsetindex[i,'month'] & data$Channel_group1 ==subsetindex[i,'Channel_group1'] & data$Brand == brand, ]
  #other code
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks this error check - in data.frame "data" there are more channel groups a the check seems to comp only the first element of data$Channel_group1 if its = to stanica and overall loop proceeds only for TV station which is first in data. But I am going try this subsetindex

Comment: Hmm... I use subsetindex and get this again   Error in aggregate.data.frame(mf[1L], mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...) : 
  no rows to aggregate     It's weird because I subsetted data manually on command line replacing i by every possibility and it had aggregated data all the time

Comment: Ok I figured out the problem . In other code there were subsets based on numerical values. And one particular tv stations has lot of volatility and unlikely scenario that no brands will come close to certain numeric value occured. Now works great thanks